# When using the multinom function from the nnet package, how can I control the architecture of the neural networks?

Tags: r, neural-network

In other words, when I do `nnet(...)` I can use the size parameter to control the number of units in the hidden layer. My particular model requires outputting probabilities so I wanted logistic units and so I turned to multinom from the nnet package to output type='probs' in my predict function. How can I pass down a size argument? When I call it with, say, size=5 or something I get an error:

```
 formal argument "size" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Comment: nnet
Error: object 'nnet' not found

Comment: multinom appears to have hard coded `size = 0` in its calls to nnet.default. I suspect there's a mathematical reason for this, but don't feel comfortable speculating further.

Comment: library('nnet')..also, yes it seems to be size=0 which sounds like it's identical to just logistic regression!

Comment: @PalaceChan: the difference is that `multinom` can handle factor responses with 3 or more levels, while logistic regression (as implemented in `glm`) is for binary responses only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`multinom` fits *linear* multinomial logistic models, which is why the size parameter is hardcoded to 0. If you want an actual neural network with multinomial outputs, just use `nnet` with a response with more than 2 levels, and set `softmax=TRUE`.