# Can I use neuronal networks from the R package nnet to model compositional data?

Tags: r, neural-network, nnet, proportions

I am working with compositional data (proportions that sum up to 1) in R and I have already tried Dirichlet regressions as a parametric approach for modelling and predict on new data. I would like to test non-parametric approaches such as neural networks, random forest or CNN and I found the package `nnet` with the function `multinom()`, which in the manual says that "Fits multinomial log-linear models via neural networks". However, I also found in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969440/when-using-the-multinom-function-from-the-nnet-package-how-can-i-control-the-ar) that this function is not really calling any `neural network` whatsoever since the argument `size` (size of the hidden layer) is set to 0, which converts this function into a parametric approach if I understood correctly.

In the same question, it was suggested to just use `nnet()`function with a response with more than 2 levels, and set `softmax=TRUE`, but I dont know how to do this and I get an error if I try to model directly the proportions (see reproducible example).

Given an reproducble example dataset like this one:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 300 # Number of observations

# Simulate predictor variables
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n * 10), nrow = n, ncol = 10))
names(data) <- paste0("V", 1:10)

# Simulate proportions for A, B, C that sum to 1
proportions <- matrix(runif(n * 3), ncol = 3)
row_sums <- rowSums(proportions)
proportions <- sweep(proportions, 1, row_sums, "/")
data$prop_A <- proportions[,1]
data$prop_B <- proportions[,2]
data$prop_C <- proportions[,3]

# Split into train/test
train_indices <- sample(1:n, size = 0.8 * n)
train_data <- data[train_indices, ]
test_data <- data[-train_indices, ]

# Fit nnet model with softmax=TRUE
model <- nnet(prop_A + prop_B + prop_C ~., data = train_data, size = 2, softmax = T)
>
> Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, ...) : 
>   'softmax = TRUE' requires at least two response categories
>
```

I would like to know if `nnet` is a plausible non-parametric approach to model compositinoal data and how would an experienced person takkle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this with cito. cito is a package for fitting DNNs with a simple user interface (including formula syntax), but with the advantage of using state-of-the-art DL frameworks (here torch).

Unlike nnet, cito supports custom loss functions and I think we can build what you want (unfortunately we do not have multinomial loss at the moment because it is not yet implemented in torch):

```
library(cito)

# Custom loss functions must be implemented in torch 
custom_loss = function(pred, true) {
  pred_prob = torch::nnf_softmax(pred, dim = 2)
  return(torch::nnf_binary_cross_entropy(pred_prob, true))
}

# Model call, by default a DNN with two layers and each with 50 nodes
model = dnn(cbind(prop_A, prop_B, prop_C)~., data = data, loss = custom_loss, lr = 0.1)

# Predict
pred =predict(model)

# To forward them through the softmax link, we must transfer them to a torch object
pred_tensor = torch::torch_tensor(pred)

# Predictions - we must apply the link, and then transform it back to R
torch::nnf_softmax(pred_tensor, dim = 2)  |> as.matrix()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. This is already implemented in the package Compositional. The function is called kl.compreg().